# Android EditText loading late

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-view

When I am trying to display a text in `EditText` using `setText()` method  the `EditText` view is displayed after the execution of function succeeding the `setText()` method call. Why?

Comment: post your code so that we know what you are trying.

Comment: First I read a file into edittext view using settext.in the function following I carry out texttospeech conversion.But edittextpanel is displayed only after the execution of texttospeech conversion.Both are carried out in onCreate()

Comment: Updates to the UI can only happen once your code returns from `onCreate` and anything that is executed in the UI thread. You have to move texttospeech into an AsyncTask

Comment: Thank you, it worked when done according to info described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put long running code in seperate thread so that it does not tieup the application that calls it.Updates to the UI can only happen once your code returns from onCreate and anything that is executed in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

`setText()`, or anything that updates the widget-based UI, is not immediate. `setText()` does not actually set any text directly. Instead, `setText()` and kin create a message object, containing their request, and put that object on a message queue. The main application thread (a.k.a., UI thread), when it is not executing your callback methods like `onCreate()` and `onClick()`, will pull messages off this queue and process them.